# What would a society where humans coexist with a second species with the intelligence of an 8 year old look like?

Tags: society, species

An alternate Earth has two species coexisting in it: Humans and Khnosh (/x'ʔɒʃ/) **since the Stone Age**. Adult Khnosh have the intelligence of the average 8 year old human but the strength of a human adult. Humans and Khnosh **cannot interbreed with each other**. Khnosh have the body shape of humans, but have blue skin and orange eyes that make them visually distinct from each other. **The ratio of Humans to Khnosh is 4:1.**

Khnosh are capable of performing simple, repetitive tasks such as screwing caps on bottles, assembling furniture, cooking food in restaurants, lifting and organizing boxes, and farming (without the use of complicated machines). They **can** live on their own and perform most tasks needed for independent living (making beds, cooking, brushing teeth, etc.) but most Khnosh **cannot** perform certain functions in life (ex. paying taxes).

Humans first encountered Khnosh in Anatolia (Western Turkey) when both species were living as hunter-gatherers. From Anatolia, they soon spread throughout Europe, followed by the Eastern Hemisphere, and were introduced into the Americas by European colonists. This means that Native Americans did **not** have Khnosh in the pre-Columbian era.

So what would a society where humans coexist with a second species with the intelligence of an 8 year old look like?

Comment: 1 question per post, narrow enough to not require a book to be answered. please

Comment: I revised my question. Is it good to go now?

Comment: It's still quite broad, but I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica, is this question focused enough to be reopened?

Comment: I still count 3 questions, and some of them opinion based.

Comment: So I revised it to contain only 1 question. Are you good with it now?

Comment: Goes outside. "Are there 8yo people here? Yes!"  Points at what he found outside.

Answer (score 6):

> So what would a society where humans coexist with a second species with the intelligence of an 8 year old look like?

Look back into slavery.

Every culture that said "this race is mentally unable to do X." Well, now it's true. Only need to replace maids, butlers, farmhands, drivers with you homemade race.

Comment: Slavery, all the way

Comment: @Gustavo, would enslaving Khnosh be any different than enslaving human beings with an average IQ of 100?

Comment: @galactic_analyzer slavery needs not a reason, barely an excuse. The people in the story could point fingers because they look different, even if they were bona fide DaVinci.

Comment: This exactly, except that the 8-year-old slaves will be much easier to control than historical slaves were, owing to the Knosh's _genuinely_ inferior mental abilities. The Knosh will never produce a Frederick Douglass, an Ida B Wells, a Martin Luther King, Jr. History suggests that the Knosh will be universally, systematically exploited, to everyone's detriment.

Answer (score 1):

from Wikipedia.
"The average IQ of a young adult with Down syndrome is 50, equivalent to the mental ability of an eight- or nine-year-old child"

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Down_syndrome#:~:text=The%20average%20IQ%20of%20a,individual%20are%20usually%20genetically%20normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Down_syndrome#:%7E:text=The%20average%20IQ%20of%20a,individual%20are%20usually%20genetically%20normal).

So the entire race would be humans with down syndrome.